# Probability problem(pmf, avg value, var, allocation) : hitting an enemy until he dies

Tags: probability

> There is a soldier armed with a sword that can cause 1, 2, 3 or 4 damage points ,with probability of $\dfrac{1}{4}$ for each value of damage points, to an enemy. Therefore, all hits with the sword cause lose of health points of the enemy. An enemy has 5 health points. The solier consecutively hits the enemy until the sum of the damage points he caused to the enemy is greater or equal than 5 so the enemy dies. Hits are independent. Let the random variable $Y$ that describes how many hits were made so the enemy to die. Calculate $p_Y$(mass), $F(Y), E(Y), VAR(Y).$

I see that $Y$ can take values from 2 to 5. For example: $p_Y(5) = P_X(1,1,1,1,1)+P_X(1,1,1,1,2)+P_X(1,1,1,1,3)+P_X(1,1,1,1,5)+P_X(1,1,1,1,5)=\cdots$

I guess $P_X(1,1,1,1,1) = \dfrac{1}{4}\cdot\dfrac{1}{4}\cdot\dfrac{1}{4}\cdot\dfrac{1}{4}\cdot\dfrac{1}{4}$

But i see that it's not efficient to calculate pmf this way, because i will have to add more probabilities for $p_Y(4),$ then for $p_Y(3)$ etc.

Any hits for what do? Basically, i don't know how to start and then calculate pmf. Then, probably i would be able to calculate the average value and all the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

More generally define $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,Y_4,Y_5$ where $Y_k$ denotes the number of hits needed if $k$ hits are enough to overcome the enemy.

Further let $D$ denote the number of damage points achieved by the first hit.

Then $Y=Y_5$ and: $$P(Y_5=n)=\frac14\sum_{d=1}^4P(Y_5=n\mid D=d)=\frac14\sum_{d=1}^4P(Y_{5-d}=n-1)=\frac14\sum_{d=1}^4P(Y_{d}=n-1)$$So this provides a way to find the PMF by recursion.

Likewise expectations (hence variance) can be found by recursion:

$$\mathbb{E}Y_{5}=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{d=1}^{4}\mathbb{E}\left(Y_{5}\mid D=d\right)=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{d=1}^{4}\left[1+\mathbb{E}\left(Y_{5-d}\right)\right]=1+\frac{1}{4}\sum_{d=1}^{4}\mathbb{E}\left(Y_{d}\right)$$
and:
$$\mathbb{E}Y_{5}^{2}=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{d=1}^{4}\mathbb{E}\left(Y_{5}^{2}\mid D=d\right)=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{d=1}^{4}\mathbb{E}\left(1+Y_{5-d}\right)^{2}=1+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{d=1}^{4}\mathbb{E}\left(Y_{d}\right)+\frac{1}{4}\sum_{d=1}^{4}\mathbb{E}\left(Y_{d}^{2}\right)$$